# Visual Studio Code - how to debug node.js routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

So I have my app structured like this:

```
server.js
    router
       routes
          emails.js
    index.js
```

I have my route defined in index.js like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
app.use('/emails', require('./routes/emails'));
};
```

And emails.js has a simple get route that looks like this:

```
router.get(/*'/emails */'/:id', function (req, res, next) {
   console.log('route hit');
})
```

I put breakpoints on each line (app.use, router.get and console.log). When I first launch my app, the breakpoints for app.use and router.get are hit. When I make my API call, my code executes but my breakpoint is never hit.

I'm assuming that this is some internal Node.js thing that I need to configure VS code for, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Does anyone know a way to get this to work? I really want to use routes and not have a massive server.js file, but not without the ability to debug with the IDE.

Comment: And what does the API call look like, what URL is that using, your current route matches only `/emails/something`, not `/emails/` not `/` or anything else for that matter

Comment: `router.get()` runs at startup and registers a route handler.  `router.get()` is not called again.  Instead, you need to set a breakpoint inside the specific callback that was registered as the route handler and that breakpoint will get hit when the route is matched by an incoming request.  This has nothing to do with node.js, but instead is how callbacks registered as event handlers work (a design pattern used a lot by node.js, but not unique to node.js).

Comment: Adeneo - I know the route is correct because the code is executing.

Comment: jfriend00 - I'm trying to wrap my head around that... with my breakpoints I can see the route being set up when server.js starts, but I'm not sure how to set a breakpoint inside the callback differently (not on console.log). Do I need to move my code out into a different function and call it from router.get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what was happening... I'm posting in case someone else finds this problem. The solution was deceptively simple - moving this code in server.js:

```
var router = require('./router')(app);
```

to execute before I set up the server variable. I don't have a whole lot of time to dive into why this made a difference, but I hope it helps someone... order of endpoints in Express is very important!

Answer (score 0):

Just put debugger on the lines where you want to break the code and run node debug server.js from terminal.

https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have opened the application via your command prompt and then you are using VSCode debugger.

**Somehow VSCode debugger is not throwing an error about the port already taken but debugging not works in this case if app has already started with command prompt.**

Close your application launched from command prompt and put break point inside callback and try. it works:)